# Can we add datetime picker to datagridview's columns in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datetimepicker

Can we add datetime picker to datagridview's columns in winforms? with or without coding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with some amount of code you can get it working, the good news is that you find examples ready for copy/paste, snippet:

```
public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

...

public class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{

...
```

full article: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)